# Serialization How to dynamicly ignore all members of a specific type

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlignore

I want to ignore all elements of Dictionary while serializing as those members cause an exception

example class:

```
public class TestClass{
    public string StringTest { get; set; }
    public int IntTest { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> someDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

What i tried(unsuccessfull)

```
XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();
attrs.XmlIgnore = true;

xOver.Add(typeof(Dictionary<int, string>), attrs);

XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(objectToConvert.GetType(), xOver);
serialiser.Serialize(writer, objectToConvert);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't there an XML-serializable dictionary in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124597/why-isnt-there-an-xml-serializable-dictionary-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this instead.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Dictionary<int.string> someDictionary{get;set;}
```