# xmlserializable dictionary implementation in C# using Space efficient xml

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Are there any known dictionary implementations in C# that space efficiently persists itself as XML.

- It should support generics
- it may assume that all elements inserted are of the generic type (ie. no subtype is inserted) - Hence the type information can be written once, rather than for each key-value pair.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't there an XML-serializable dictionary in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124597/why-isnt-there-an-xml-serializable-dictionary-in-net)

Comment: space efficient XML is compressed XML (not XML per se, but it is the standard approach)

Comment: I dont want the type Information to be persisted again and again as it is done in the so-called duplicate link above.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said,

> space efficient XML is compressed XML (not XML per se, but it is the standard approach)

Consider using compression. In a webserver setting, most browsers support gzip encoding *transparently* out of the box. So this applies to your garden-variety XML Ajax responses as well

---

Otherwise, implement [IXmlSerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) so you can control exactly how things are serialized.

I remember seeing a number of nice articles, e.g.

1. [How to Implement IXmlSerializable Correctly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ImplementIXmlSerializable.aspx)
2. Cannot find the 'good' article (my a wellknown MVP community person... don't remember right now. Chris Sells?) Here is an alternative [article combining LINQ-to-XML with IXmlSerializable](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4639/customize-xml-serialization-using-ixmlserializable/)

Comment: Its not for a webserver but storing data in a DB. I have a look at the links although an actual implementation would have been nice :)