# Returning generic object with generic dictionary from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service with the following method:

```
[OperationContract]
TernaryWebServiceResponse<long> ModifyObservations(...);
```

Response object is as following:

```
[DataContract]
public class TernaryWebServiceResponse<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public TernaryProcessingResultStatus ProcessingSuccessStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<T, bool> ProcessingSuccessDetails { get; set; } 
}
```

This class is defined in a shared assembly and WCF reference is configured to reuse it.

But when I generate the proxy, I get something like this:

> Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail: An exception
>   was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Referenced type 'TernaryWebServiceResponse`1, General,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' with data
>   contract name 'TernaryWebServiceResponseOflong' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/Genaral.SoapCommunication'
>   cannot be used since it does not match imported DataContract. Need to
>   exclude this type from referenced types.

Can somebody plz explain me, what is exactly the problem here? I know that generics can be used in WCF contracts as long as they are resolved, e.g. not `MyObj<T>` but `MyObj<long>`. So what's wrong with this class? Is it that T defined on the class cannot be somehow resolved on the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe defining a new contract will help. 
Something like:

```
[DataContract] 
public class LongTernaryWebServiceResponse : TernaryWebServiceResponse<long> 
{ 
}
```

And then in your service contract something like:

```
[OperationContract]
LongTernaryWebServiceResponse ModifyObservations(...);
```

Comment: I marked it as an answer coz I actually used this in the end, although it does not explain why this happens. The problem was in fact with dictionary serialization. In some cases writing a serializable dictionary wrapper (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124597/why-isnt-there-an-xml-serializable-dictionary-in-net) would work, just in case smb else stubles over this question.

Answer (score 0):

If the generic type for the class is only needed for the Dictionary key, you may be able to do something along the lines of this (untested) ...

```
[DataContract]
public class TernaryWebServiceResponse
{

    [DataMember]
    public TernaryProcessingResultStatus ProcessingSuccessStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    private Dictionary<object, bool> mProcessingSuccessDetails;

    static public TernaryWebServiceResponse Create<T>(Dictionary<T, bool> list)
    {
        var dc = new TernaryWebServiceResponse();
        dc.mProcessingSuccessDetails = new Dictionary<object, bool>();
        foreach (var pair in list)
        {
            dc.mProcessingSuccessDetails.Add((object)pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
        return dc;
    }

    public Dictionary<T, bool> ProcessingSuccessDetails<T>()
    {
        return mProcessingSuccessDetails.ToDictionary(x => ((T)x.Key), x => x.Value);
    }

}
```