# Deserialisation doesn't rebuild dictionaries that are members of classes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I've got some serialisation code set up as follows:

```
    static void SerialiseObject(Object o, String path)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
        stream.Close();
    }
    static Object DeserialiseObject(String path)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Object o = (Object)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return o;
    }
```

And a class with the following member defined:

```
[Serializable]
public class CircuitModel
{
    public Dictionary<String, Bus> Buses { protected set; get; }
    ...
}
```

I populate the Dictionary, and then the following code successfully serialises and deserialises the dictionary, with all `Bus` objects intact:

```
SerialiseObject(CircuitModel.Buses, "temp.bin");
Object o = DeserialiseObject("temp.bin");
```

But when I try to do the same for `CircuitModel`:

```
SerialiseObject(CircuitModel, "temp.bin");
Object o = DeserialiseObject("temp.bin");
```

`CircuitModel.Buses` has been initialised, but is empty.

I've also tried implementing serialisation with `ISerializable` (for the `Bus` and `CircuitModel` classes) and had exactly the same problem

Any idea as to why this would be happening?

Comment: and can you try using private backend Dictionary field instead of automatic property?

Comment: @MarekKembrowski is there any advantage to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have something more sinister going on with your child collection because binary serialization of Dictionaries within classes does work just fine.

```
    [TestFixture]
public class SerializeTest
{

    [Test]
    public void TestSer()
    {
        var parent = new Parent
                        {
                            Name = "Test"
                        };
        parent.Children.Add("Child1", new Child {Name = "Child1"});
        parent.Children.Add( "Child2", new Child { Name = "Child2" } );

        SerialiseObject(parent, "test.bin");
        var copy = DeserialiseObject("test.bin") as Parent;

        Assert.IsNotNull(copy);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, copy.Children.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(copy.Children.ContainsKey("Child1"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Child1", copy.Children["Child1"].Name);
    }

    static void SerialiseObject( Object o, String path )
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream( path, FileMode.Create );
        formatter.Serialize( stream, o );
        stream.Close();
    }
    static Object DeserialiseObject( String path )
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream( path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read );
        Object o = (Object) formatter.Deserialize( stream );
        stream.Close();
        return o;
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Parent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Child> Children { get; protected set; }

        public Parent()
        {
            Children = new Dictionary<string, Child>();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Child
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The children deserialize with the parent and contain the details they were initialized with. I would check any code that is setting your `Buses` collection. My example just did it in the constructor of the parent class, but it may be possible that you have rogue code setting it after it's been deserialized?

Comment: That your setter for Buses is marked as `protected` leads me to believe that your actual scenario is a bit more complex. Collections should typically be initialized on construction. Normally I use a pre-initialized private field with a public/protected getter for collections... Having that protected setter in use somewhere is probably tripping you up.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'd already tried drawing out the `Dictionary` into a private field and a public getter before I'd posted here on SO, but that didn't help the situation.

Comment: Just found the problem! I was having problems because I was trying to access child elements before they'd been deserialised. They were still deserialising, just after my [OnDeserialized] hook.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not serializable. Remove the dictionary if you need to serialize that data, and replace it by a list of a custom class that contains the data in the dictionary:

```
[Serializable]
public class BusItem
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Bus Bus {get;set;}
}
```

Edit: I just found out you can actually serialize Dictionaries using the `DataContractSerializer` instead.

http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-xml-serialize-or-deserialize-dictionary-in-csharp/

Comment: Yeah, I've been serialising Dictionaries for ages. They work fine with DataContractSerializer, and also with `BinaryFormatter`. The issue is with the Dictionary not serialising *only once its in a class*

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about XML serialization, it might be because Dictionary is not serializable to XML. Look at [Why isn't there an XML-serializable dictionary in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124597/why-isnt-there-an-xml-serializable-dictionary-in-net/5941122#5941122).

Comment: My question clearly indicates that I'm not using XML serialisation.

Comment: Sorry, I posted too quickly. Just came across the the XML issue and spot your question afterwards.