# WCF - Generic Dictionary Name Problems

Tags: wcf, generics

So, I'm consuming a WCF service where a colleague has created functions like this:

```
<OperationContract()>
Function GetRelationshipsGroupedByClass(ByVal objId As Integer, ByVal showDeleted As Boolean) As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Relationship))
```

When I create the service reference in my asp.net application the return type is no longer a dictionary but

```
ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringArrayOfRelationshipQknDUPatKeyValueOfstringArrayOfRelationshipQknDUPat
```

Is there any way of giving WCF a custom name to call this instead of this crazy name?  Or am I going to have to rewrite all the functions that use generic dictionaries to output custom data contracts instead?

Answer (score 1):

Because Dictionaries are [not inherently serializable into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124597/why-isnt-there-an-xml-serializable-dictionary-in-net)  , WCF converts it into an array - the array you see in your service reference. You may choose to create your own serializable dictionary - [here's one](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/one-way-to-serialize-dictionaries/), or use custom data contracts as you suggested.

Comment: Yeah, I know why it does it. I was hoping there was a way of telling WCF what to call its output class. Perhaps an attribute on the function or something.