# Data type with string, string that can be serialized/de serialized to xml

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

In C#, can someone please inform me of the best data type that can have a `string, string` combination that can be `serialized` to `xml` and `de serialized` from `xml`?

I need to be able to have a `list` of this object, and the `list` can also be `serialized` to `xml` and `de serialized` from `xml`.

I have tried `dictionary` type, but this is causing errors when `serializing` to xml.

I am using object `xml` `serialization` for the `serialization`.

What data type should I use? Does such a data type exist?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I can serialize a `List<string[]>`, but am wondering if another data type does exist.

Comment: when you say two string ,is the first string attribute and the other value or how will the resulting XML look like eventually ?

Comment: It is basically just a string string pair that I am looking for and I am using object xml serialization. So the xml looks different depending on the object type.

Comment: `NameValueCollection` is not supported too.

Comment: List<string[]> does what is required, but am wondering if there is a different data type that will work.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671259/how-to-xml-serialize-a-dictionary, or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787286/dictionary-xml-serialization, or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554186/how-to-serialize-deserialize-to-dictionaryint-string-from-custom-xml-not-us, or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799767/easy-way-to-convert-a-dictionarystring-string-to-xml-and-visa-versa